# postback from Google Play Campaign Attribution

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I implemented campaign tracking from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) in my android app

I am promoting my android app on different adnetworks who require install postback from install tracking sdk(GA in my case), how to get server to server postback in Google Play Campaign Attribution after successful install?
thanks